# Regular expressions in Notepad++. How make pattern that could be use in a few lines

Tags: c#, c++, regex, notepad++

I have to Find and Replace some lines for one click in Notepad++!
How can I to do that?
 
**Text:**

```
//A lot of code
 int i = n << 3;
 cout << "message1";
 cout << "message1" << var1 <<"message2"<< var2 << /* undefened length */ << var50; 
 cout << "messageA1" << endl;
 cout << "messageA1" << varA1 <<"messageA2"<< varA2 <<  /* undefened length */ << endl << varA67 << endl;
//A lot of code
```

**Find:** "SomeAwesomePattern";
**Replace:** "SomeAwesomeReplacerFor"
**Result:**

```
//A lot of code
int i = n << 3;
Console.Write("message1");
Console.Write("message1" + var1 + "message2" + var2 + /* undefened length */ + var50);
Console.Write("messageA1" + "\n");
Console.Write("messageA1" + varA1 + "messageA2" + varA2 + /* undefened length */+"\n" + varA67 +"\n");
//A lot of code
```

**Operations:**

> replace  **cout <<**  by  **Console.Write(** 
>    replace **<< endl** by **"\n"**
>   rpelace **<<** by **+**
>  rpelace **;** by **);**
>   
>   **It must ignor**
>    all text that didn't start with **cout**

Comment: _`printf("message1" + var1 + "message2" + var2 + /* undefened length */ + var50);`_ won't work well anyways.

Comment: This looks like the perfect example of an XY problem.  Perhaps you'd be better off trying to ask about why cout isn't suitable for you

Comment: Sorry. Right ! It'll didn't work.. OK. How about: string someText = "message1" + var1 + "message2" + var2 + /* undefened length */ + var50;

Comment: I changed task a litle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer as a general exercise, run

- replace all `cout.*<<.*\K<<` with  `+`, many times until it can't match.
- replace all `cout.*<<.*\Kendl` with `"\\n"`, many times
- replace all `cout.*<<.*\K(?<!\))(?=;)` with `\)`
- replace all `cout.*<<`with `Console.Write\(`

from [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

- `\K` (Keep the stuff left of the \K)
- `(?<!`..`)` A zero-width negative lookbehind assertion.
- `(?=`..`)` A zero-width positive lookahead assertion.

Comment: Thank you broo!. I'll try it. I changed task a litle. How about find and replace **endl** by **"\n"**